# TIBCO Global variables, reverse engineering

Tags: tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I'm currently working on a project were am at the stage of figuring out what the current implementation is doing. Have been putting in a lot of time (A LOT) searching connections between queues declared as global variables.

Is there a way to get a listing of were a specific global variable is being used, or do I actually need to go through all processes, as I´m doing atm?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

in Tibco Designer 5.8 you can find where global variable is used using **"Tools->Find Global Variable usages"** menu item.

Please note that all tibco processes source code are text files. So, you also can search inside project folder using file text search from any utility that allowing you to search inside text files. For windows I prefer [Far Manager](https://www.farmanager.com/)
In the "Far manager" you can navigate to project folder then <kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and search for

> %%GLOBAL_VARIABLE_NAME%%

Please also note that even if you don't have tibco project source code you can get it from tibco BW server. example path

> tibco\tra\domain\tibco\datafiles\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME